# Python/Pandas Dataframe - Replace decimal precision with int value when 0 else round to n decimal places

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Using the below construct to remove the decimal precision (. & 0) when the value is say 3.0 and round to 4 decimal places when the value is say 3.12345

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Price':[1.0,2.12345,3.0,4.67892]})
df1["Price"] = df1["Price"].apply(lambda x: round(x,4) if x%1 else int(x))
print(df1)
```

The rounding works, but not the conversion to int.

Comment: I think it's impossible... Usually, a column will have the same `dtype` across all values, so when you convert something to int, and reinsert it to the df, the type returns to `float64`.

Comment: Youc can add this code to your existing code. `df1["Price"].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace('.0',''))` This will convert the column to data type `object` though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transform the column to an object type, using `dtype=object`:

```py
df1["Price"] = np.array([int(x) if x%1==0 else round(x,4) for x in df1["Price"].values ], dtype=object)

    Price
0       1
1  2.1234
2       3
3  4.6789
```

As you can see below, the objects hold `int` and `float` where necessary:

```py
[print (type(i)) for i in df1["Price"].values]

Out[1]
<class 'int'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: No problem @Sri

Comment: With your advice on making the df1["Price"] series of type object, the below casting also works,


`df1["Price"] = df1["Price"].apply(lambda x: round(x,4) if x%1 else int(x)).astype(object)`